# .Net - Update reference dll Automatically

Tags: .net, web-services, dll, reference

Greetings

i have a C# (VS 2005) webservice and it has a reference to .Net librabry dll (i.e. MyLibrary.dll).
When we build the webserice and dll for first time, dll had version 1.0.0.1.

But due to some project requirement, we .Net librabry dll was recompiled and its version is changed to 2.0.2.1 (but there was no change to interface)

This dll is not registered in GAC, it is always in local "Bin" folder

But webservice did not pickup new version of dll (but it was refering to older version) and we endedup with recomipling the webservice with new version of dll.

is there anyway (sorry for basic question) that webserivce automatically pick up new version of reference .net DLL ?

many thanks.
Venu

Answer (score 2):

Is the old DLL registered in GAC? If yes it will always be picked up first. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1606273/net-assembly-loading-priorities) for assembly loading priorities.

Also there might be a reference to the old version (including assembly version information) in web.config/app.config etc. It is possible to configure a binding redirection (see [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/thottams/archive/2007/01/30/introduction-to-versioning-and-bindingredirect.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eftw1fys(v=VS.100).aspx) about how to do it).